# React native works very slow on android

Tags: react-native

By 'Very slow' i mean, it loads a single transition about 5 second despite this is just a simple example app.

[Here is the whole app RN code](https://gist.github.com/mdcsfk/55519ae0f05236e60782)

Take a look at `onPressFeed`

Answer (score 14):

This saved me a lot of time:

- **Search your code for "console.log", and comment them before testing.**
- **Turn off "JS Dev Mode"**

You will want to make sure that you turn off "JS Dev Mode," or else it
will run painfully slow on device.

This is how you disable JS Dev Mode on Android:

After running "react-native run-android" you should "shake" your device
to bring up the menu. Select "Dev Settings" then uncheck "JS Dev Mode."

After that run "react-native run-android" again and it should be more
performant, at least I hope for you :)

Source: https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/issues/199

Comment: How would you test the app if dev mode is off?

Answer (score 5):

### Turn logging off in production

In your entry file try adding the following snippet:

```
if (!__DEV__) {
  console.log = () => {};
}
```

This will allow console logs to work during development, but when you release for production it is just an empty function call.

Comment: hi, where to put this line? Thanks

Comment: @famfamfam as early as possible, most likely in your index.js or app.js

Answer (score 2):

What version of React Native are you running? And what phone are you running it on?

If you run React Native on an Android Emulator, it'll be pretty slow. Also, if you have chrome debugging on, it slows the app down a LOT.

I'm running a fairly simple React Native app on my Samsung Galaxy s4 device, and it runs fairly quickly (animations run pretty smoothly too).

some example code that I run (a sidedrawer and main view with animation):

```
_renderCancel: function(){
  if (this.state.showView) {
    return (
      this.props.view
    );
  } else {
     return ;
   }
},

render: function() {

var menu = <Menu 
              closeDrawer={this.closeDrawer}
              navigator={this.props.navigator} 
              modifyOnClose={this.modifyOnClose} />;


return (
  <Drawer
    ref="drawer"
    onClose={this.onClose}
    type={this.state.drawerType}
    animation={this.state.animation}
    openDrawerOffset={this.state.openDrawerOffset}
    closedDrawerOffset={this.state.closedDrawerOffset}
    panOpenMask={this.state.panOpenMask}
    panCloseMask={this.state.panCloseMask}
    relativeDrag={this.state.relativeDrag}
    panStartCompensation={this.state.panStartCompensation}
    openDrawerThreshold={this.state.openDrawerThreshold}
    content={menu}
    styles={drawerStyles}
    disabled={this.state.disabled}
    tweenHandler={this.tweenHandler}
    tweenDuration={this.state.tweenDuration}
    tweenEasing={this.state.tweenEasing}
    acceptDoubleTap={this.state.acceptDoubleTap}
    acceptTap={this.state.acceptTap}
    acceptPan={this.state.acceptPan}
    changeVal={this.state.changeVal}
    negotiatePan={false}
    side={this.state.rightSide ? 'right' : 'left'}
    >
    <View>
      <CustomToolBar onPress={this.openDrawer}/> 
      {this._renderCancel()}   
    </View>
  </Drawer>

);
},
```

this runs fairly quickly on my device.

Comment: RN 0.19, device: philips Xenium
it drops 100+ frames during a single transition
debugging off

Comment: I like reactjs, but seems, react native has so many issues - is it possible to actually create smooth working application there? i've found issues on rn repo - seems it will work slow anyway. Not as it does now, but ~1 second delays - that's not good.

Comment: RN is slower on Android than iOS (works nearly perfectly on iOS) but they are working on it. It's the beginning only so let's have a bit of patience there.

Comment: Hmm yeah I don't think React Native works terribly well just yet, and it is fairly new (a lot of android functionality JUST got implemented)... hopefully it speeds up for you. On my phone I get decent performance, hopefully that will apply to most phones soon.